# А есть ли такое в Django?

Tags: django, django-admin

Собственно такой вот вопрос:
Например у меня есть повторяющиеся данные на сайте - телефон, название компании и т.п. Можно ли вывести в административной панели такую настройку, без возможности создавать новые объекты? Т.е. одно значение и всё, только редактировать. На данный момент выношу в отдельный html и потом include в нужном месте. Как вариант, но приходится при таких случаях править файл.

Comment: Вы можете регулировать это через права пользователей

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько помню, в Django нет стандартного функционала для модифицирования данных, которые не хранятся в моделях. Но вы можете сами написать Форму, которая будет загружать и сохранять данные в файл, и вьюху для отображения. Это легко сделать, если почитать исходники Django

Если все таки очень хочется хранить эти данные в админке, то лучше использовать модели. Можно ограничить их кол-во до 1го и сделать перенаправление на этот объект при переходе в список объектов модели. Как минимум это избавит от множества вероятных ошибков вроде недоступности файла или получения доступа из вне. И вообще модели с ОРМ - фишка django

Вы можете убрать can_add и can_delete из ModelAdmin, оставив только can_change; change_view - делаете редирект на страницу изменения объекта, при сохраненнии стоит тоже добавить редирект, чтобы сообщения о сохранении через django.messages исправно отоброжались. Что касается создания первого и единственного объекта, можете попробовать написать соответсвующией код в миграции, либо написать management_command для ее создания (как сделали исторически у меня на работе).

Еще можно создать модель с полями "Тип данных", "Значение" с уникальным ключем по "Тип данных", и тогда вы можете создавать сколько угодно параметров сайта и выводить где угодно в шаблоне, например, с помощью шаблонных тегов или переменные контекста, поместив их в контекст через middleware. Запрос будет выполняться быстро, так как вероятно у вас не будет 100500 параметров для сайта

---

UPDATE: Подробнее о последнем обзаце

Создайте модель, вроде

```
class SettingsModel(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    value = models.TextField() # Или CharField
```

И список ключей, или Enum объект, при использовании EnumField (приложение django-enum-fields или как то так)

```
SETTINGS_PROPS = [
    'phones': 'Телефоны',
    'email': 'E-Mail',
    'cookies': 'где лежат печеньки',
    ...
]
```

Для ModelAdmin формы переопределете поле, даете ему choices

```
class SettingsModelForm(form.ModelForm):
    ...
    key = forms.CharField(...., choices=SETTINGS_PROPS)
```

Пишите фильтр или шаблонный тег на основе какого-нибудь примера из django, что то вроде (см. доку)

```
@register.simple_tag
def insert_data(data_key):
    return SettingsModel.objects.filter(key=data_key).first().value
```

и в шаблоне используйте что то вроде

```
{% insert_data 'phones' %}
{% insert_data 'email' %}
```

Comment: Довольно расширенный ответ. А можно подробнее по информации из крайнего абзаца?